# What's the selectedIndex value of a dropdownlist control when a prompt text is set?

Tags: apache-flex

When using a dropdownlist in flex I'd like to know the exact index value when the prompt is initialized in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's usually -1

(I've never had an answer so short I needed to add text for SO to allow it!)

Comment: You could've said: "I'm just about absolutely certain it is quite a minus one right there, sir."